# Mac OS X 10.10 php 5.5.14 free type support

Tags: php, macos

It appears the GD library is installed, but free type is not. How can I add this to my php installation in mac os x 10.10 system php install?

Answer (score 3):

I would install [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and then use:

```
brew install freetype
```

Comment: How do I get this into my php configuration in mac os x 10.10

Comment: You would then need to recompile PHP with the flags from http://php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php. I would consider using https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php because compiling PHP is never fun.

Answer (score 2):

To get this configured with php

```
brew remove --ignore-dependencies --force php71
brew install php71 --with-freetype
```

Then make sure to load this brew installed php into your apache httpd.config, and restart your apache server.

```
LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.1/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
```

Comment: invalid option: --with-freetype